# How can I resize an image in Photoshop without losing quality?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, resize

I have made a logo in Photoshop which I want to use in a banner for a website. A small problem, however, is that I made the logo way too large (I figured that if I would make the logo large enough, I would always have a sharp image). I now know that's not the case and I'm stuck with a logo which has a height of about 100cm and I cannot figure out how to resize it so that it fits in a banner with a height of 300 pixels without drastically losing quality. Is there any way this can be done? Or should I just start over creating a logo of a more moderate size?

Comment: Hi M Plomp, Welcome to GD.SE! What settings are you using to downsize the logo? What are your export settings when saving the logo? Can you show an example of the drastically lower quality image? Besides all of that, it is best to create logos in a vector program so that you're able to scale the logo to any size.

Comment: Hi @AndrewH ! If I downsize my logo (it's a PNG file) in Photoshop using image > image size.. I make sure to check Bicubic Sharper. However, I need my logo to be about 4% of its original size. Is there anything else I can try? Next time I'll make sure to use Illustrator or something like that...

Comment: We have no clue what your logo have. If it have heraldic like lions and dragons you probably notice the blur more than a plain typographic one. Post an image.

Comment: If you used a lot of effects including Blending Options, it may be better to save it as a png (since it's anyway for a website), and resize it there. Save it for the web (and resize it in this window).

Answer (score 0):

Go to image > image size… enter desired pixel value and select the forth option in the dropdown and press enter. here's an image of what your menu should look like (it's from german photoshop though)

[image: et voilà]

Comment: I have tried this and it still makes my logo pixelated. I guess the reduction is too much..

Comment: Do you look at the logo at 100%?